# Sum function picking wrong values

Tags: vba, excel, sum, worksheet-function

I have activated "sheet2" but even then the sum function is taking up values from "sheet1" instead of "sheet2".

```
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(fl1, nf) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(fl1, locrng1.Column), Cells(fl1, (nf - 1))))
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(fl1, of) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(fl1, nf) * Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(fl1, firstlevel1.Offset(0, 1).Column)
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(fl1, rf) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(fl1, nf) * (1 - (Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(fl1, firstlevel1.Offset(0, 1).Column)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get to know using the `With` statement, it will save you a lot of typing.

**Note**: where in your code do you `Set firstlevel1` range ? it might be before you used `Activate` with `Worksheets("sheet2").Activate`.

*Remember* there's almost never any reason to use `Activate`, it only slows down your code run-time.

Try the code below:

```
With Worksheets("sheet2")
    .Cells(fl1, nf) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(fl1, locrng1.Column), .Cells(fl1, (nf - 1))))
    .Cells(fl1, of) = .Cells(fl1, nf) * .Cells(fl1, firstlevel1.Offset(0, 1).Column)
    .Cells(fl1, rf) = .Cells(fl1, nf) * (1 - (.Cells(fl1, firstlevel1.Offset(0, 1).Column)))
End With
```